# Como calcular o valor do input em JavaScript e o resultado aparecer no alerta?

Tags: javascript, html5

Eu não sei o porquê não está calculando e nem mostrando o resultado no alerta.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Agência de viagens</title>
    <link href="estilo.css" rel="Stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Pacifico|Roboto+Slab:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

          <form method="POST" action="index.php">


    <h2>Opção de destinos:</h2><p></p>

    Lisboa: 250€<input type=radio name="cidade" id="Lisboa" onclick="cidValor(250.0)" value="250€"><br>
    Paris: 250€<input type=radio name="cidade" id="Paris" onclick="cidValor(250.0)" value="250€"><br>
    Londres: 250€<input type=radio name="cidade" id="Londres" onclick="cidValor(250.0)" value="250€"><br>
    Roma: 250€<input type=radio name="cidade" id="Roma" onclick="cidValor(250.0)" value="250€"><br>
    Miami: 250€<input type=radio name="cidade" id="Miami" onclick="cidValor(250.0)" value="250€"><br>


    <br>Quantidade de pessoas no quarto: <br><p></p>
    Solteiro: 35€<input type="radio" name="dormitorio" id="Solteiro" onclick="calculo(35)" value="35€"><br>
    Casal: 60€<input type="radio" name="dormitorio" id="Casal" onclick="calculo(60)" value="60€"><br>
    3 pessoas 120€<input type="radio" name="dormitorio" id="4_pessoas" onclick="calculo(120)" value="120€"><br>
    5 pessoas: 180€<input type="radio" name="dormitorio" id="8_pessoas" onclick="calculo(180)" value="180€"><br>


   <input type="submit" name="salvar" id="submit" value="Enviar">
   <input type="Reset" name="apagar" type="text"  value="Apagar tudo">


   <script type="text/javascript">

   var valorCidade=0;

   function cidValor(valor){ valorCidade=valor;}

   function calculo(vlDormitorio){
     if (valorCidade <> 0){
          alert(valorCidade+vlDormitorio);
     }else{
          alert('Cidade não informada');
     }
  }

   </script>

        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você já pegou o valor pelo id direto na tua função calculo?

Comment: No if você está comparando valorCidade diferente de 0, correto? Utilize != não <>.

Comment: Parece que o seu verdadeiro problema são os operadores javascript.  veja 
este [post](https://www.devmedia.com.br/javascript-como-e-quando-utilizar-os-operadores-e/37782)  sobre operadores javascript de igualdade e desigualdade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no seu **javascript**, na função **calculo**, o operador de diferente no javascript é o **!=** e não o **<>** como você está utilizando.
Segue a função corrigida:

```
function calculo(vlDormitorio){
     if (valorCidade != 0){
          alert(valorCidade+vlDormitorio);
     }else{
          alert('Cidade não informada');
     }
  }
```

Comment: valeu, era isso mesmo que estava dando errado

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer esse teste, e diz o que deu no console ou no `alert()`.

```html
...
<input type="hide" id="valor_cidade">
...
```

```js
function cidValor(valor){
   $("#valor_cidade").val(valor);
}

function calculo(qtde){
     var valor_cidade = $("#valor_cidade").val();
     alert(valor_cidade + qtde);
     console.log(valor_cidade + qtde);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Além do erro do operador de *diferença* `<>` (o correto é `!=` ou `!==`), eu sugeriria mudanças no seu código, começando pela remoção dos inúmeros atributos `onclick`. Em vez de usar 1 `onclick` em cada radiobutton, você poderia usar um `event listener` que já pega os cliques em todos os radios de uma só vez. Já iria economizar vários bytes de código.

Outra coisa é deixar nos values dos radios apenas o valor numérico, sem o símbolo do Euro `€`.

Veja como fica o código, bem mais simples e enxuto (veja explicações nos comentários):

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
   
   // elemento clicado
   var el = e.target;
   
   // se o elemento clicado tiver o name "dormitorio"
   if(el.name == "dormitorio"){
      
      // pega o valor do radio "cidade" marcado
      var cidade = document.querySelector("[name=cidade]:checked");
      
      // verifica se alguma cidade foi marcada
      if(!cidade){
         alert('Cidade não informada');
         el.checked = false; // desmarca o radio
      }else{
         alert(+cidade.value + +el.value);
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="index.php">

   <h2>Opção de destinos:</h2><p></p>
   
   Lisboa: 250€<input type=radio name="cidade" id="Lisboa" value="250"><br>
   Paris: 250€<input type=radio name="cidade" id="Paris" value="250"><br>
   Londres: 250€<input type=radio name="cidade" id="Londres" value="250"><br>
   Roma: 250€<input type=radio name="cidade" id="Roma" value="250"><br>
   Miami: 250€<input type=radio name="cidade" id="Miami" value="250"><br>
   
   
   <br>Quantidade de pessoas no quarto: <br><p></p>
   Solteiro: 35€<input type="radio" name="dormitorio" id="Solteiro" value="35"><br>
   Casal: 60€<input type="radio" name="dormitorio" id="Casal" value="60"><br>
   3 pessoas 120€<input type="radio" name="dormitorio" id="4_pessoas" value="120"><br>
   5 pessoas: 180€<input type="radio" name="dormitorio" id="8_pessoas" value="180"><br>
   
   
   <input type="submit" name="salvar" id="submit" value="Enviar">
   <input type="Reset" name="apagar" type="text"  value="Apagar tudo">

</form>
```